# Does AllFramesReady event provides the synchronized color frame and depth frame?

Tags: c#, kinect

I am a newbie to Kinect and recently trying to use C# to save the color frame and depth frame in PNG and binary format respectively for future use. One critical requirement of this task is color frame and depth frame synchronization, that is, both frames should correspond to the same logic scene.

I know AllFramesReady event can provide color frame, depth frame and skeleton frame, at one time, but are these frames synchronized? After checking the saved frames, it turns out they are shifted about two or three frames. is this acceptable?

All replies are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AllFramesReady event will give you the most closely matched frames available. If you are running both color and depth at 30 frames/s, then the AllFramesReady event will fire at 30 frames/s. If you are running color at a lower frame rate, AllFramesReady will fire at the slower rate (and you'll miss any depth frames that don't correlate to a color frame).

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/kinectsdknuiapi/thread/2e172449-3d18-4914-9370-fbc1cfa31aa6)

There is a [tutorial](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectQuickstart/Camera-Fundamentals) about the AllFramesReady event to synchronize data between the color, depth, and skeletal frames .